# What is resolved first, an card when-player-summon effect or a summoned card effect?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm playing with an Alien deck, and one thing I like to do with this is to activate [Planet Pollutant Virus](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Pollutant_Virus) combined with [Alien Mars](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Mars) and [Alien Psychic](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Psychic).

My question is when my opponent summons a monster that has a effect, which resolves first? E.g.

1. My opponent plays a monster that can destroy another monster when summoned
2. My [Planet Pollutant Virus](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Pollutant_Virus) places an A-Counter on it
3. My [Alien Mars](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Mars) negates my opponent monster's effect

or

1. My opponent plays a monster that can destroy another monster when summoned
2. My [Planet Pollutant Virus](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Pollutant_Virus) places an A-Counter on it
3. My opponent monster's effect is resolved so it destroys my [Alien Mars](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Mars) before it's effects are negated

Comment: Could you please add links of each card by highlighting a card and pressing Crtl + L, then adding a link from www.yugioh.wikia.com with that card name?

Comment: _"My opponent plays a monster that can destroy another monster when summoned"_ - please elaborate

Comment: @VortexYT Sorry about this. It seems that you got the question after all, as your answer is clear to me. I didn't get the downvotes, tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain activation 1: *Opponent's monster summoned, and tries to destroy your monster.* **SS1 (SS2 if quick effect)**

Chain Activation 2: *Planet Pollutant Planet activates* **SS2**

**Where is Alien Mars? Because it is a SS1, it cannot be activated in this chain**

Chain Resolution 2: *An A-Counter is put on your opponent's monster.*

Chain Resolution 1: *Your opponent destroys your Alien Mars*

Therefore, your opponent's monster destroys your monster, but you managed to put an A-Counter on it with your Planet Pollutant Virus.

Comment: This is a clear answer. Didn't know about SS1 and SS2. If there was two SS2, how does the resolving happens?

Comment: The card activated last is resolved first

Comment: This is incorrect. Alien Mars' effect is continuous, not activated; as soon as an A-Counter is placed on the opponent's monster, its effect is negated by virtue of Mars being on the field. The chain would resolve with that monster's effect being negated, so Mars would not be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the current answer to this question is wrong. Alien Mars does not activate it's effect because it doesn't have an activated effect; it's effect is continuous. The chain order would be:

Chain link 1: monster is summoned, and it's effect is activated. Note that the summon doesn't start a chain, but the effect does.

Chain link 2: an A-Counter is placed on the opponents monster

On resolution, the counter would be added. Since the opponent's monster has a counter on it, it's effect is negated. This is because the effect of Mars is continuous, and doesn't need its own chain link.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back this up?

Comment: If you check the wikia page [here](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Mars), you can see that the effect is continuous. If you check the page on continuous effects [here](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Continuous_Effect), you can see that they don't start chains or have chain links. This means that once the counter is on the monster, it will have it's effects negated if Alien Mars is on the field and Mars' effects are not negated.

Comment: You should provide that information in your answer so that others can see it as well without having to search for it.

Comment: Can someone confirm it? I always thought this way, until I asked this question here. Now I'm confused.